# No funciona dispose() en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Este es el codigo del Frame principal:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Venta extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ChangeListener, ItemListener {

    private JLabel micro, mother, memoria;
    private JComboBox listaMicro;
    private JCheckBox monitor, disco;
    private JRadioButton asus, gigabyte, msi, dosmb, cuatromb, ochomb;
    private ButtonGroup mothers, memorias;
    private JTextField total;
    private JButton calcular, ver, salir;
    private int precioMicro;
    private int precioMadre;
    private int precioMemoria;
    private int precioDisco;
    private int precioMonitor;
    private int estadoImporte;

    public Venta() {
        setLayout(null);
        micro = new JLabel("Tipo de Micro:");
        micro.setBounds(100, 50, 150, 30);
        add(micro);
        mother = new JLabel("Placa madre: ");
        mother.setBounds(30, 150, 150, 30);
        add(mother);
        memoria = new JLabel("Memoria: ");
        memoria.setBounds(30, 250, 150, 30);
        add(memoria);
        listaMicro = new JComboBox();
        listaMicro.setBounds(300, 50, 150, 30);
        listaMicro.addItem("Intel");
        listaMicro.addItem("Atlon");
        listaMicro.addItem("Turion");
        add(listaMicro);
        listaMicro.addItemListener(this);
        listaMicro.setSelectedIndex(1);
        mothers = new ButtonGroup();
        asus = new JRadioButton("Asus");
        asus.setBounds(240, 150, 150,30);
        asus.addChangeListener(this);
        add(asus);
        mothers.add(asus);
        gigabyte = new JRadioButton("GigaByte");
        gigabyte.setBounds(390, 150, 150, 30);
        gigabyte.addChangeListener(this);
        add(gigabyte);
        mothers.add(gigabyte);
        msi = new JRadioButton("Msi");
        msi.setBounds(540, 150, 150,30);
        msi.addChangeListener(this);
        add(msi);
        mothers.add(msi);
        memorias = new ButtonGroup();
        dosmb = new JRadioButton("2 MB");
        dosmb.setBounds(240, 250, 150,30);
        dosmb.addChangeListener(this);
        add(dosmb);
        memorias.add(dosmb);
        cuatromb = new JRadioButton("4 MB");
        cuatromb.setBounds(390, 250, 150, 30);
        cuatromb.addChangeListener(this);
        add(cuatromb);
        memorias.add(cuatromb);
        ochomb = new JRadioButton("8 MB");
        ochomb.setBounds(540, 250, 150,30);
        ochomb.addChangeListener(this);
        add(ochomb);
        memorias.add(ochomb);
        monitor = new JCheckBox("Monitor");
        monitor.setBounds(90, 300,150,30);
        monitor.addChangeListener(this);
        add(monitor);
        disco = new JCheckBox("Disco");
        disco.setBounds(240, 300, 150, 30);
        disco.addChangeListener(this);
        add(disco);
        calcular = new JButton("Calcular Importe");
        calcular.setBounds(30, 400, 180, 40);
        calcular.addActionListener(this);
        add(calcular);
        ver = new JButton("Ver Dialogo");
        ver.setBounds(30, 500, 180, 40);
        ver.addActionListener(this);
        ver.setEnabled(false);
        add(ver);
        total = new JTextField("0,00");
        total.setBounds(300, 400, 180, 40);
        add(total);
        salir = new JButton("Salir");
        salir.setBounds(300,500,180,40);
        salir.addActionListener(this);
        add(salir);
        estadoImporte=0;
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent f) {

        if(f.getSource()==listaMicro) {

            String tmicro = (String) listaMicro.getSelectedItem();
            if (tmicro.equals("Intel")) {
                precioMicro=150;
            }
            else if(tmicro.equals("Atlon")) {
                precioMicro=80;
            }
            else {
                precioMicro=120;
            }
        }
    }

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent g) {

        precioMonitor=0;
        precioDisco=0;

        if(asus.isSelected()==true) {
            precioMadre=75;
            }
        if(gigabyte.isSelected()==true) {
            precioMadre=320;
        }
        if(msi.isSelected()==true) {
            precioMadre=100;
        }

        if(dosmb.isSelected()==true) {
            precioMemoria=50;
        }
        if(cuatromb.isSelected()==true) {
            precioMemoria=80;
        }
        if(ochomb.isSelected()==true) {
            precioMemoria=130;
        }
        if(monitor.isSelected()==true) {
            precioMonitor=250;
        }
        if(disco.isSelected()==true) {
            precioDisco=80;
        }
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==calcular) {
            // ya que se presiono calcular habilita para ver el dialogo
            estadoImporte = 1;
            // hace la suma de los componentes, formatea y los coloca en el textfield
            float totalgral = precioDisco+precioMonitor+precioMemoria+precioMicro+precioMadre;
            String cadena=String.format("%.02f", totalgral);
            total.setText(cadena);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==salir) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (estadoImporte == 1) {
            // habilita el dialogo porque se presiono calcular
            ver.setEnabled(true);
            if (e.getSource()==ver) {
                String tmicro = (String) listaMicro.getSelectedItem();
                Dialogo dialogo1 = new Dialogo(tmicro, total);
                dialogo1.setBounds(50,50,500,500);
                dialogo1.setVisible(true);
            }
        }   


        }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Venta formulario1 = new Venta();
        formulario1.setSize(700, 650);
        formulario1.setVisible(true);
        formulario1.setResizable(false);
        formulario1.setTitle("Venta de Computadoras");


    }

}

// y este es el del JDialog donde no me funciona el dispose()

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Dialogo extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel etiqTipoMicro;
    private JLabel etiqImporte;
    private JLabel tipoMicro;
    private JLabel importe;
    private JButton cerrar;

    Dialogo (String tmicro, JTextField total){
        setLayout(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setModal(true);
        JLabel etiqTipoMicro = new JLabel("Tipo de Micro: ");
        etiqTipoMicro.setBounds(30, 30, 150, 30);
        add(etiqTipoMicro);
        // recupera el tipo de micro
        JLabel tipoMicro = new JLabel(tmicro);
        tipoMicro.setBounds(200, 30, 150, 30);
        add(tipoMicro);
        JLabel etiqImporte = new JLabel("Importe Total: ");
        etiqImporte.setBounds(30, 100, 150, 30);
        add(etiqImporte);
        // recupera el texto del textfield
        JLabel importe = new JLabel (total.getText());
        importe.setBounds(200, 100, 150, 30);
        add(importe);
        JButton cerrar = new JButton("Cerrar");
        cerrar.setBounds(300, 300, 150, 30);
        cerrar.addActionListener(this);
        add(cerrar);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==cerrar){
         dispose () ; 

            }


    }

}
```

Comment: como que no te funciona? no hace nada? da error? Hace algo pero no lo que esperabas? Intenta ser más específico con el comportamiento que tiene tu programa y el comportamiento que esperas tú

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mucho cuidado con lo siguiente:**

La clase `Dialogo` tiene 2 `JButton` llamados `cerrar`, uno global y `private` y el otro a nivel del constructor de la clase.
El metodo `actionPerformed` hace uso del `JButton` global, el cual **no esta instanciado**, por tanto si lo accionas no ocurrirá nada.

La solución es que modifiques `JButton cerrar = new JButton("Cerrar");` por `cerrar = new JButton("Cerrar");` para instanciar aquel `JButton` que se declaro privado y global.

De hecho todos los elementos globales de esa clase no los instancias sino que usas nuevos componentes desde el constructor, eso podria traerte muchos dolores de cabeza pensando en proyectos a gran escala porque, entre otras cosas, duplicas código y mantenerlo se vuelve tediosamente costoso.